# Read third enum constructor value by passing initial 2 values

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have below `enum`

```
public enum MyTest{
     READIT("1", "2", "3");
}
```

In my class I have `"1"` & `"2"` coming dynamically, however the name given to enum i.e. `READIT` is  unknown to my class, passing initial 2 values that is `"1"` & `"2"` I want to read the third constructor value i.e `"3"`

Enum can be read by `value()` or `valueOf(String s)` method. Where String s will be `READIT`, which is unknown to my class. `value()` will return array which needs to be iterate to get the third value. Is there any way to read third or any value depend upon the other values passed to enum.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what `values()` for an `Enum` class does. `values()` iterates over the *enum types*, not the values you define for a particular enum type. Why not define a method for your enum and use that?

Comment: it would help to have a more thorough sscce to clarify what you're talking about here.

Comment: My basic need is to read the enum constructor value by passing other known constructor values to it. In above example, I have "1" and "2" available in other class (which is using this enum). And using such "1" & "2" values I want to read the third value of READIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would locate an enum based on fields present in it. If you have an enum with parameters, those are getting stored somewhere. If they are private than you can use reflection to get at them.

```
enum MyEnum {

    A("1", "2", "3"), B("4", "5", "6");

    final String s1;
    final String s2;
    final String s3;

    private MyEnum(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.s3 = s3;
    }
}

public class MyEnumExample {
    static String readThirdValue(String first, String second) {
        for (MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()) {
            if (e.s1.equals("1") && e.s2.equals("2")) {
                return e.s3;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String thirdValue = readThirdValue("1", "2");
        if (thirdValue == null) {
            System.out.println("no matching enum found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("found " + thirdValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice ! it worked. In loop will add dynamic values to compare with. (first and second instead of "1" & "2")